# Invoking a method when WCF service is started

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service (VS 2010, .Net 4.0) hosted as a Windows service.
What I want to do is this: I want a method which is in the service to be executed when the service is started.

Comment: what did you try? how do you start the WCF host in your Windows Service? Show your OnStart method implementation please

Comment: To do what? There is an override somewhere to customize configuration etc.

Comment: @DavidePiras I don't have an OnStart method. Actually, that's my problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't understand you. How do you mean "There is an override somewhere to customize configuration etc."?

Comment: His question is legit. Why would you call a method on the service from the host itself? And how can you have a Windows Service without an OnStart method?

Comment: @CodeCaster There is OnStart method on the Windows service, but there isn't one in the WCF service. I don't want to call a method from the host. I want to call the method from the WCF service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how you have used Windows Service to host your WCF service(s) but I would expect something like @SSamra described.

Anyway, below the line wherever you do **.Open();** to open your service, you could initialize your wcf proxy and call your method.

Say your proxy is FirstWcfProxy, then you can do something like,

```
var firstWcfProxy = new FirstWcfProxy(); 
// or IFirstWcfService firstWcfProxy = new FirstWcfProxy();

firstWcfProxy.YourMethod();
```

EDIT:
If you want to ensure the method is called as soon as the service is started, initialize your proxy below the line **sHost.Open();** and invoke the method there, like I described above

Comment: I'm gonna go with this. Tnx :)

Answer (score 3):

```
how about

    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Windows_Service
{
  public partial class WCFWindowsService : ServiceBase
  {
    ServiceHost m_serviceHost;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
      m_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(FirstWcfService.Service));
      m_serviceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
      if (m_serviceHost != null)
      {
        m_serviceHost.Close();
      }
      m_serviceHost = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have .svc file. Actually, the projcet is WCF library service. As I said, I don't have OnStart method.

Comment: @user96 OnStart belongs to the Windows (NT) Service. But I'm starting to think you are using IIS hosting. Do you create a ServiceHost somewhere?

Comment: No, I don't use IIS hosting. I use windows hosting.

    sHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFserviceLibrary.Jobs));
    sHost.Open();

I want to call a method from WCFserviceLibrary.

Comment: In my answer WCFWindowsService is container for the service FirstWcfService.Service

Comment: if you are saying it is a windows service then you need a service container that actually runs your service
and first thing this container will call is onstart which is when you start your service from the services options of your os.

now if think you do not want to call your service method from servicecontainer

then your only option left is to call that method of the constructor of your service
but be careful and if it is just intialization code then make sure it is only called once using some sort of flag